# How to give the exact URL of my static image folder to frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js code which uploads images to a directory using multer.

Lets say I uploaded the images inside a public folder and in response I get the following:

```
    originalname: 'zz.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: '/public/companyA',
    filename: '6c1c6e29edb14e9021fe-zz.jpg',
    path:
     '/public/companyA/6c1c6e29edb14e9021fe-zz.jpg',
    size: 193302 }
```

Then I made the public folder as static in Express:

`app.use(express.static(public))`

I am giving this response to Frontend and I want to add the full path in my response with the environment which my application is running like if I am running the code in my localhost, it should show like:

```
    originalname: 'zz.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: '/public/companyA',
    filename: '6c1c6e29edb14e9021fe-zz.jpg',
    path:
     '**localhost:3000/companyA/6c1c6e29edb14e9021fe-zz.jpg**',
    size: 193302 }
```

Or if I am running the code inside a server with IP, it should be like:

```
    originalname: 'zz.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: '/public/companyA',
    filename: '6c1c6e29edb14e9021fe-zz.jpg',
    path:
     '***IP/companyA/6c1c6e29edb14e9021fe-zz.jpg***',
    size: 193302 }
```

All I need is a trick that give me *localhost:3000* or *IP:PORT*. So that I can add it to response.

Comment: You don't need to do anything in this case.
As stated the file is stored in the public folder using multer and you are having the file name and path.
So as it is public folder, so the link will automaticlly have the localhost/IP/domain. in front of the file/image url

Comment: In other case, if you need the data to be across another domain/ server. Then you can use the process.env.publicUrl and append it to the link being sent to the client.